# Autogenerar código MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas

```
-Categoria (IdCategoria, NombCategoria)
-Producto (IdProducto, CodProducto, NombProducto)
```

Quisiera que el CodProducto se autogenere de acuerdo a la Categoría que se escoja. Por ejemplo:

```
CATEGORÍA
(1 VIDEOJUEGOS)
(2 CELULAR)
(3 TV)

PRODUCTO
(1 VI001 PES2020)
(2 VI002 Dragon Ball z)
(3 TV001 Control Remoto)
(4 CE001 Cargador)
(5 TV002 Cable Audio/Vídeo)
```

Que de acuerdo a la categoría que se escoja se vaya incrementando

Comment: No entendí del todo la pregunta, pero me parece que tendrás que programar un `TRIGGER` para eso. La duda es sobre cómo se insertan los datos por ejemplo o por qué realmente necesitas hacer algo así ¿?

Comment: Te recomiendo primero crear un campo adicional en la tabla CATEGORIA que almacene el PREFIJO que utilizaras para armar el código del producto (VI, TV, CE). Luego puedes usar triggers para hacer un update en dicho código utilizando la funcion CONCAT() de MySQL. Creo que con esa información podrás proseguir.